# Label smoothing (soft targets) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

In Pandas there is [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) method that one-hot encodes categorical variable. Now I want to do label smoothing as described in section 7.5.1 of [Deep Learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/) book:

> Label smoothing regularizes a model based on a softmax with *k* output values by replacing the hard *0* and *1* classification targets with targets of `eps / k` and `1 - (k - 1) / k * eps`, respectively.

What would be the most efficient and/or elegant way to do label smothing in Pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, lets use much simpler equation (`ϵ` denotes how much probability mass you move from "true label" and distribute to all remaining ones).

```
1 -> 1 - ϵ
0 -> ϵ / (k-1)
```

You can simply use nice mathematical property of the above, since all you have to do is

```
x -> x * (1 - ϵ) + (1-x) * ϵ / (k-1)
```

thus if your dummy columns are `a, b, c, d` just do

```
indices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
eps = 0.1
df[indices] = df[indices] * (1 - eps) + (1-df[indices]) * eps / (len(indices) - 1)
```

which for

```
>>> df
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  0  1
3  1  0  0  0
4  0  1  0  0
5  0  0  1  0
```

returns

```
        a         b         c         d
0  0.900000  0.033333  0.033333  0.033333
1  0.033333  0.900000  0.033333  0.033333
2  0.033333  0.033333  0.033333  0.900000
3  0.900000  0.033333  0.033333  0.033333
4  0.033333  0.900000  0.033333  0.033333
5  0.033333  0.033333  0.900000  0.033333
```

as expected.

Comment: Indeed, equation you proposed is much simpler. Thank you!