# Possible/maybe category in deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm interested in taking advantage of some partially labeled data that I have in a deep learning task. I'm using a fully convolutional approach, not sampling patches from the labeled regions.

I have masks that outline regions of definite positive examples in an image, but the unmasked regions in the images are not necessarily negative - they may be positive. Does anyone know of a way to incorporate this type of class in a deep learning setting?

Triplet/contrastive loss seems like it may be the way to go, but I'm not sure how to accommodate the "fuzzy" or ambiguous negative/positive space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try *label smoothing* as described in section 7.5.1 of [Deep Learning book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/):

> We can assume that for some small constant `eps`, the training set label y is correct with probability `1 - eps`, and otherwise any of the other possible labels might be correct.
>
> Label smoothing regularizes a model based on a softmax with `k` output values by replacing the hard 0 and 1 classification targets with targets of `eps / k and 1 - (k - 1) / k * eps`, respectively.

See my question about [implementing label smoothing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335535/label-smoothing-soft-targets-in-pandas).

Otherwise if you know for sure, that some areas are negative, other are positive while some are uncertain, then you can introduce a third *uncertain* class. I have worked with data sets that contained *uncertain* class, which corresponded to samples that could belong to any of the available classes.

Comment: Thanks for this. I could figure out what to call it and was having trouble finding the right idea - I'll see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you are struggling with a data segmantation task with a problem of a ill-definied background (e.g. you are not sure if all examples are correctly labeled). Recently I came across the similiar problem and this is what I came across during my research:

1. In *old days* before deep learning and at the begining of deep learning era - the common way to deal with that is to *smooth* your output with some kind of a probability model which would take into account the possibility of a noisy labels (you could read about this in a **Learning to Label from Noisy Data** chapter from this [book](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vmnih/docs/Mnih_Volodymyr_PhD_Thesis.pdf). It's important to discriminate this probabilistic models from models used to smooth your labels w.r.t. to image or label structure like classical CRFs for bilateral smoothing.
2. What we finally used (and worked really well) is the Channel Inhibited Softmax idea from this [paper](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/ist/jist/2016/00000060/00000001/art00003). In terms of a mathematical properties - it makes your network much more robust to some objects not labeled - because it makes your network to output much higher positive valued `logits` at correctly labeled objects.

Answer (score 2):

You could treat this as a semi-supervised problem. Use the full dataset without labels to train a bottleneck autoencoder structure (or a GAN approach). This pretrained model can then be adjusted (e.g. removing the last layers, adding a better layer structure at the end on top of the bottleneck features) and finetuned on the labeled data.