# Keras categorical model

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to create a Keras deep learning algorithm to identify coniferous and leafed trees from a false-colour orthophoto. I have extracted around 4 500 training/validation images which are considered to be correct, such as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xiph.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZtSS.jpg). The pixel size in real-world is 0,5 meters so these are not really high-res images. All images are fixed-size 31x31 px. The following model is a product of googling, especially Keras' own documentation site.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 30, 30

train_data_dir = 'treedata/train'
validation_data_dir = 'treedata/validation'
nb_train_samples = 4000
nb_validation_samples = 533
epochs = 50
batch_size = 16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(2)) # number of classes
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='rmsprop',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save('treetypes.h5')
```

From epoch 2 onwards, the accuracy claims to be > 0.99 and loss < 0.02, which I find odd. After creating the model, I try to go through an orthophoto and decide if one 30x30 px sub-image contains a tree of given type.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image

model = load_model('treetypes.h5') 
roi = cv2.imread('roi.jpg')
sy, sx = img.shape[:2]
px_apart = 10 # start sub-images 10 px apart
s = 30 # sub-image size

for starty in range(1, sy-img_height, px_apart):

    for startx in range(1, sx-img_width, px_apart):

        subimg = img[starty:starty+s, startx:startx+s]
        x = image.img_to_array(subimg)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        is_tree = model.predict(x, batch_size=1, verbose=0) # predict classes
```

This is where I get lost. First and foremost, there seems not to be a choice that a sub-image is neither a coniferous nor leafed tree (all sub-images get predicted either is_tree = [[0, 1]] or is_tree = [[1, 0]]). There are not for example predictions [[0.1, 0.02]], which would suggest that this sub-image is not a tree at all. Thus, two main questions:

1) Have I understood correctly that the model should output probabilities for belonging to class 1 (coniferous) and class 2 (leafed)? Why it does give only "binary" results? I read somewhere that softmax scales sum of probabilities to 1.

2) Is my model anywhere near usable? Or is it even viable to use NN for this, given coarse sample resolution? I suspect some overfitting for my model...

Thanks in advance if anyone has time to take on this!

Answer (score 0):

If you use softmax, the sum of the two classes will be 1. That means you will never get a "no tree" result.

But if you change the activation to "sigmoid", then you can have both zeros (and also both 1). You might, if your model or your data is not that good, end up with "yes to coniferous" and "yes to leafed".

You may also try an approach of creating three classes instead, and go back to softmax. Class1 = coniferous; Class2 = leafed; Class3 = None.

---

About your model.

Well, this is an art. Only testing a lot and reading success cases you will find the best model for the task.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have only two classes in your dataset. So I'd like to propose you an interesting technique called *channel inhibited softmax* in order to have an additional *maybe* category which you may read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898437/possible-maybe-category-in-deep-learning). In order to use this category you need to add the additional 3rd output from network to `softmax` layer which is constantly equal to `0`. Now you have two options here:

1. You could retrieve the input to `softmax` from your model and add an artificial `0` to it:

   ```
   logits_model = Model(model.input, model.layers[-2].output)
   data = logits_model.predict(x)
   final_probs = numpy.exp(x) / (numpy.sum(numpy.exp(x), axis = 1) + 1)
   ```

   The advantage of this way is that you don't need to train a new model but use an existing one.
2. You could train a new model:

   ```
   def channel_inhibited_softmax(x):
       e = K.exp(x - K.max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True))
       s = K.sum(e, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.exp(-K.max(x), axis=1)
       return e / s

   model.add(Activation('relu'))
   model.add(Dense(2)) # number of classes
   model.add(Lambda(channel_inhibited_softmax))
   ```

   Now you could retrain your model with additional *not sure* class.

Thanks to solutions above - you could add an uncertainty to your model and check if it's likely that a given picture doesn't belong to any of classes.